# Combining two select statements with differing returns into a single view

Tags: sql, t-sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have a T-SQL stored procedure I'm trying to convert to PL-SQL.

Currently, this stored procedure executes a very long select query, immediately followed by a much shorter select query. It looks like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name        
    @userid    int,
AS          
    select   (about twenty fields)
    from     (about five tables)
    where    something = @userid

    select   (about five fields)
    from     (about three tables)
    where    something = @userid
```

My first thought when I saw this was to convert it to a view, since it's just doing a select statement. However, is this actually possible, given that two selects are being done? Could a stored procedure be used? I've experimented with that idea, but to my understanding I'd need to create two sys_refcursors, meaning the calling code would need to handle both query returns differently, which it's not having to do currently.

So question is: How can I convert that type of procedure, from T-SQL, to PL-SQL?

Comment: That procedure is working now?

Comment: How is your currently calling code not having to handle the results differently?  And that is not a valid variable name in TSQL.

Comment: That isn't the exact procedure - that's just what I wrote to make it succinct. The variable name is valid, apologies for confusion. Currently, the calling code just refers to any attribute it wants. The attributes in both queries are different and it just seems to know which *select* query to take its results from.

Comment: Even is TSQL will let you do that I am surprised you would want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply have a `select` query in `PL/SQL`. It will throw `PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement` error.

To return multiple rows, you could use `CURSOR`. In your case, with multiple statements, you can have two `REFCURSOR`.

For example,

```
SQL> variable v_ref1 refcursor
SQL> variable v_ref2 refcursor
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_ref1 sys_refcursor;
  3    v_ref2 sys_refcursor;
  4  BEGIN
  5    OPEN :v_ref1 FOR SELECT empno, ename
  6       FROM emp ORDER BY empno
  7    FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
  8    OPEN :v_ref2 FOR SELECT empno, ename
  9       FROM emp ORDER BY empno DESC
 10    FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
 11  END;
 12  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print v_ref1

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH
      7499 ALLEN
      7521 WARD
      7566 JONES
      7654 MARTIN

SQL> print v_ref2

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7934 MILLER
      7902 FORD
      7900 JAMES
      7876 ADAMS
      7844 TURNER

SQL>
```

If you want to combine the resultset of your multiple `SELECT` statements, you could use `UNION` operator and have it in single `REFCURSOR`. Given that the column data types match and are in proper order. It is just an example,

```
SQL> variable v_ref refcursor
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_ref sys_refcursor;
  3  BEGIN
  4    OPEN :v_ref FOR
  5      SELECT empno, DEPTNO FROM emp WHERE ROWNUM <=5
  6         UNION ALL
  7      SELECT empno, DEPTNO FROM EMP WHERE ROWNUM <=5;
  8  END;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print v_ref

     EMPNO     DEPTNO
---------- ----------
      7369         20
      7499         30
      7521         30
      7566         20
      7654         30
      7369         20
      7499         30
      7521         30
      7566         20
      7654         30

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Whilst I appreciate your answer, I did state in my question that I was aware of ref cursors but that the columns in both queries *do not match* - so this doesn't really answer my question. Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: You mean you need a single resultset from two separate queries?

Comment: Yeah, if possible. Basically, that's what's *currently* happening in T-SQL, so I need to replicate it as near as possible.

Comment: How could you combine two different resultsets with different number of columns, data types? There has to be some alignment.

Comment: I don't know. That's what I'm asking. T-SQL can do it. Does Oracle have any mechanisms to do it?

Comment: You can explicitly combine the two SQLs using `UNION` operator, but you need to align the columns properly and make sure each select has equal number of columns and similar data type.

Answer (score 0):

You could make second select query have 20 columns as well by making the fields which are not there in the first select query NULL. But that depends if you are okay with that.